# Problem detecting and using a nullable value in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a POJO object that I have serialized from JSON (in Java).  I am using an object wrapper constructed via:

```
      DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder builder = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27);
      builder.setExposeFields(true);
      objectWrapper = builder.build();
```

I use the `setExposeFields(true)` because the object I am wrapping is not a Java bean, but rather just a POJO that contains public fields.

I am doing the following in my template:

```
<@ConditionOccurrence co = c/>

<#macro ConditionOccurrence co>
<#list co?keys as key>
  ${key}
</#list>
${co.occurrenceStartDate!'wtf'}
${co["occurrenceStartDate"]}
A condition occurrence of: ${codesetName(co.codesetId, "any condition")}
<#if co.first!false>- for the first time in the person's history</#if>
<#if (co["occurrenceStartDate"])??>co.OSD is null: </#if>
</#macro>
```

Note, the 'c' is an element in a sequence, and is not important to the exact problem I am having.

The output of the template shows this:

```
  stopReason
  getClass
  gender
  CorrelatedCriteria
  providerSpecialty
  occurrenceStartDate
  occurrenceEndDate
  visitType
  accept
  codesetId
  hashCode
  conditionSourceConcept
  equals
  conditionType
  toString
  conditionTypeExclude
  class
  first
  age
org.ohdsi.circe.cohortdefinition.DateRange@68e62ca4
org.ohdsi.circe.cohortdefinition.DateRange@68e62ca4
A condition occurrence of: Psoriasis
- for the first time in the person's history
co.OSD is null:
```

The first set of lines are all the keys in my POJO. This is correct.
the two lines of output:

```
org.ohdsi.circe.cohortdefinition.DateRange@68e62ca4
org.ohdsi.circe.cohortdefinition.DateRange@68e62ca4
```

This is showing that the field `occurrenceStartDate` is an object of type `DateRange`.  note this could be null in some cases, so I am checking how to check for null...

The next part of the output:

```
- for the first time in the person's history
co.OSD is null:
```

This is showing that it is reading the 'first' attribute of the object correctly, and I have switched the raw JSON from 'true' to 'false' and the template responds properly to the change in this value. Note, in the object, the 'first' field is type `Boolean`.

The second line: `co.OSD is null` is what is confounding me.  I confirmed earlier that outputting the 'occurrenceStartDate' field shows that it holds a `DateRange` object. But, this statement is evaluating to TRUE (ie: it is null):

```
#if (co["occurrenceStartDate"])??>co.OSD is null: </#if>
```

I have tried with both dot notation and bracket notation. For some reason, the `??` operator on that field is saying it is null. Note, the underlying object isn't a simple String or Number type, it is a simple POJO class `DateRange` with 3 String properties on it.  Again, these are not JavaBeans, these are just POJOs.

Can anyone explain why the `??` operator says it is empty when it is clearly referencing an object?  Btw: if I attempt to access co.occurrenceStartDate at all, it results in a template error that I'm referencing a null value, so the core problem here is why does the wrapper thing it is a null?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I see you tried with `co.occurrenceStartDate` versus `co["occurrenceStartDate"]`. Just to reassure you, they do exactly the same. The second form is for cases like `co["space in name"]` or `co[dynamicName]`. Otherwise see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `??` operator means "is present", not "is missing". So your line should be:

```
<#if !(co.occurrenceStartDate??)>co.OSD is null: </#if>
```

Comment: Thank you for finding my stupid error.  I went on a wild goose-chase thinking it was a problem with POJOs and all along it was this false alarm about a field not being set when it actually was.  Thank you.